# preserving timestamp of a compilated python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason I had to distribute some compilated python scripts.

Before I start to write some workaround:
I like to know if there is a possibility to preserve the timestamp of the compilation date & time using python code.

Comment: Preserve after compilation or after distribution? How do you compile or distribute?

Comment: @pacholik is right: you must give the exact procedure as "compilation" makes little sense for an interpreted language in the general case.

Comment: Hi, I like to preserve the date after compilation. I compile the code on my computer making sure that the correct compilation date is in my versionstring by hand. After that I have a internal website to share the compiled code with the users. My goal is that this compliation date is inserted automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound somewhat complicated. I more recommend to make use of a version control system and upon building your application freeze (=write) the time of the last commit into a file which contains the version info and bunlde that with the executables you ship.

I have a [version_info](https://kallithea.openttdcoop.org/nml/files/afad0c76c40b7eaf6d4af2a3b40961c7755f2c04/nml/version_info.py) file which is called by [setup.py](https://hg.openttdcoop.org/nml/files/4cc36720aa9a2644c3776e8a1351162526391b7c/setup.py) during bundling the application, using mercurial, but it's easily adopted to git.